# How to decompress responses in apache matching extension

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-deflate

I'm trying to configure apache in order to uncompress .kmz files served to the client application (I want to avoid dealing with additional js libraries).

I've mod_deflate enabled and I added that configuration:

```
#kmz files handling
<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.kmz$">
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

The response remains compressed and the client application cannot read data. What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

mod_deflate [only supports the gzip encoding](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html#supportedencodings), but from what I can tell, .kmz files are Zip-encoded:

```
$ file test.gz
test.gz: gzip compressed data, was "test", from Unix, last modified: Thu Nov  5 10:38:11 2020
$ file test.kmz
test.kmz: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

So I think you need a different output filter:

```
ExtFilterDefine unzip-kmz \
  intype=application/vnd.google-earth.kmz \
  outtype=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml \
  cmd=/usr/bin/gunzip
AddOutputFilter unzip-kmz kmz
```

Or more simply:

```
ExtFilterDefine gunzip cmd=/usr/bin/gunzip
AddOutputFilterByType gunzip application/vnd.google-earth.kmz
```

That might work, but it doesn't specify the output content type, so if Apache doesn't get that right, you'll need to use the first form.

Notes:

- gunzip will decompress Zip-encoded data, but you could also use unzip.
- Make sure that the `intype` and `outtype` parameter values are the right content types for your system. `grep '\.km[lz]' /etc/mime.types` will show you.

Comment: Thank you. Not only your answer solved my issue: I've also learned new things about apache. :)

Comment: Glad to hear! If the answer was correct, please accept and/or upvote it.

Comment: Yes, I did... But because of my low reputation for now, upvote was recorded but not yet displayed.